# Calling defrag with subprocess.Popen on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, subprocess

After a long running process I want to call the defragmentation tool `defrag` on `Windows 7` using `Python` `subprocess.Popen` as illustrated in the example.

```
from subprocess import Popen

process1 = Popen('defrag', shell = True)
process1.wait()
print('finished defragmentation!')
```

This gives following output:

```
Der Befehl "defrag" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
finished defragmentation!
```

Sorry for the German output. Don't know how to switch to English. However, this means that the command `defrag` is not found. I tried it with `shell=False` and with a sequence as input argument. Nothing worked, but I remember that I did the same on `Windows XP`. Also calling `dir` with `Popen` works. Why doesn't `defrag` work on `Windows 7`? How can I make it run?

Comment: Just as a really dumb check, if you open up `cmd` and write `defrag` you get a help text correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. Running defrag from the command line works.

Comment: Yea again, sorry for the stupid question. Could you try doing: `Popen('Defrag.exe', shell = True, cwd='C:\\Windows\\System32\\')`?

Comment: There are no stupid questions. But specifying cwd doesn't help either. The error message is the same.

Comment: I'm winging shit by now because that should work.. It's both in the correct upper case format, path is precise..
Try running as administrator?

Comment: I also tried it as administrator with the same result. Could it depend on some safety settings that dissallow calling `defrag` from `python`. I guess using `shell=True` is the same as calling it from command line.

Comment: If it's a school or company restricted machine, yes that *might* be the reason. `shell=True` simply instructs Python to pipe whatever input as is into a pseudo-tty yes :) You could try: `Popen('cmd /C defrag', shell = True)`

Comment: This doesn't work either. I guess it is something specific to my machine. Maybe it is checked if the root process is from Windows. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yea i'm out of ideas. Good luck on this one mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can answer my own question. The problem is that I am running 32 bit `Python` on a 64 bit `Windows` machine. Using a 64 bit `Python` installation everything runs fine.